# How to pivot rows for an editable grid?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, entity-framework-5

I have a requirement to be able to enter data in an editable grid, with dynamic columns determined by the number of rows in a lookup table.  This isn't the actual example, but it's a similar, simple case of what I'm trying to do:

```
public class Student {
  public long ID {get; set;}
  public string FirstName {get; set;}
  public string LastName {get; set;}
  ...
}

public class Assessment {
  public long ID {get; set;}
  ...
}

public class AssessmentQuestion {
  public long ID {get; set;}
  public long AssessmentID {get; set;}
  public int QuestionNo {get; set;}
  public int PointValue {get; set;}
  ...
}

public class StudentAssessment {
  public long ID {get; set;}
  public long StudentID {get; set;}
  public long AssessmentID {get; set;}
  ...
}

public class StudentAssessmentAnswer {
  public long ID {get; set;}
  public long StudentAssessmentID {get; set;}
  public long AssessmentQuestionID {get; set;}
  public int PointsAwarded {get; set;}
  public string Comments {get; set;}
  ...
}
```

As per above structure, students can take a given assessment.  We can take the creation of Assessment, AssessmentQuestion, Student and StudentAssessment data as given.  Now the user is grading assessments, and she wants to go through all the test papers and enter the points awarded per student per question.  So for maximum ease of use the grader should see an editable grid, with one student name per row, and columns for each question, and they could just tab through all the cells entering points and comments (if any) for each question.  Then, on hitting "Save", the StudentAssessmentAnswer table should be populated.  Of course, the read should be with an outer join, because even if there's no StudentAssessmentAnswer joining between the student assessment and the question, we still want to enter the points.

So, how do you make a grid like this, when the number of columns depends on the number of rows in the AssessmentQuestion table for this AssessmentID?

Answer (score 0):

There are several commercially available grids that can do that (sort of), ie. [Telerik MVC grid](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/razor/grid/hierarchyserverside):

[image]